# For loop returns both if and else outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to make a Simon says game and the problem is inside my `answerCheck` function. I have it set to be called when both the generated pattern and the user pattern length are equal to 4 and to pass in the user pattern as currentLevel.

The problem is that no matter what the input of the user pattern is the function logs both correct and incorrect as well as running the code inside both statements.

```js
const pattern = [4];

function answerCheck(currentLevel) {
  for (let i = 0; i < currentLevel.length; i++) {
    if (currentLevel[i] === pattern[i]) {
      console.log("success");
      // setTimeout(nextSequence(), 2000)
    } else if (currentLevel[i] !== pattern[i]) {
      console.log("incorrect");
      // var wrong = new Audio("./sounds/wrong.mp3");
      // wrong.play();
      $("body").addClass("game-over");
      /*
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("body").removeClass("game-over");
      }, 300);
      */
    }
  }
}

answerCheck([4]);
```

Comment: It's running the code once for each element of answerCheck, so if you had pattern = [4,1] and answerCheck[[4,2]) its going to output success incorrect.

Comment: do you want to check all values?

Comment: @James is there anyway to run the function to check that each string in the user array is equal to the string in the same positionon of the computer generated array?

Comment: @isherwood I believe you misunderstood the code which is why I added that I could attatch the full code. The answerCheck is only ran when the length of the array is equal to 4 not the value of 4. Forgive me for my ignorance if I'm mistaken.

Comment: *check that each string in the user array is equal to the string in the same position* => `userArray.toString() === pattern.toString()`  - obviously only any use for a *simon* game if you only add to the `pattern` as you go - if you prebuild it then you need to check only the length of `userArray`

Comment: No need to tell me all about it down here. Just _update your question_ so the problem and the situation are more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to compare simple arrays (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)), here is one:

```js
const pattern = [4,3,2,1];

function answerCheck(currentLevel) {
  let success = currentLevel.length === pattern.length && currentLevel.every((el, i) => pattern[i] === el);
  
  if (success) {
      console.log("success");
  } else {
      console.log("incorrect");
  }
}

answerCheck([4]);
answerCheck([4,1,1,1]);
answerCheck([4,3,2,1,0]);
answerCheck([4,3,2,1]);
```

Comment: you could omit the length check and take `pattern` instead of `currentLevel` for `every`.

Comment: @NinaScholz   What if currentLevel had more elements than pattern, but the first (pattern.length) elements were correct?

Comment: they compared with `undefined` -> `false`

Comment: Only up to the length of pattern if you’re doing pattern.every.  The extra elements of current level would just get ignored, @NinaScholz https://jsfiddle.net/0kzq5cdp/

Comment: The above demo solved my problem but im a little lost with using every. I did some research and it seems simple enough, just haven't had to implement it up until now. Regaurdless, thank you for the input. Also, both patterns are reset at the end of each level to equal an empty array and answerCheck is only called when both pattern and userPattern length are equal so I dont see an issue like the one specified above becoming a problem.

Answer (score 0):

`nextSequence()` is invoked immediately since it's not wrapped around an 'anonymous' function if I'm correct, so your `setTimeout` value is not triggered.

You may try:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    nextSequence();
}, 2000);
```

or:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    nextSequence();
}, 2000);
```